# My whole scene is not being rendered

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

I've googled and tried a lot, like the common answer changing the ''Camera Clipping End'' the rendered version changes each time depending on the camera view but nothing seems to be working, I'm quite new to Blender[image: Camera View]

[image: Render View]

Comment: There's also the view Clip Start and End, in the N panel > View, have you tried?

Comment: Yes I have tried that aswell

Comment: maybe share your file (only some elements if it's too heavy): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: this setting can also be changed in camera settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your "Clipping start" and "Clipping end" settings, the "Clipping start" option can too be too low, but you could also try setting the "Clipping end" option really high, because your scene could be scaled up, so what you think is a couple of meters actually could be hundreds of meters.

These settings are second to the top in the n menu